# Inequality similar to Hoeffding

Tags: probability, inequality

I have a coin with heads probability $p_1$. I toss it $n_1$ times. Let $\hat{p}_1$ be the empirical heads probability. Then we know from [Hoeffding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) that $$P\left( \left|\hat{p}_1-p_1 \right| \geq \epsilon \right) \leq 2\exp(-2n_1\epsilon^2)$$

I found the following in a paper but cannot derive it: If we have two coins with $p_1$ and $p_2$ probability of heads, and I toss them $n_1$ and $n_2$ times, then
$$P\left ( \left|(\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2 )-(p_1-p_2) \right| > \epsilon \right) \leq 2\exp \left( \frac{-2\epsilon^2}{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}} \right)$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you tell us what paper? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like triangle inequality on the LHS and AM-HM on the RHS.